# How to zoom in/out in Firefox with Selenium/Python using FirefoxOptions()

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I want to maximize the window and zoom out to 0.8.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized') # not working
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, executable_path=r"W:\geckodriver.exe")
driver.execute_script('document.body.style.MozTransform = "scale(0.8)";') # not working
```

The window is not getting maximized nor zoomed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this instead:

```
#1st install pyautogui
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', '-') #zooms out to 80%
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', '-')
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try the following to zoom out to 0.8:

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='80%'")
```

You can use the following code to maximize:

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: driver.manage().window().maximize() gets the error: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'manage' BUT this works "driver.maximize_window()"

Comment: @TobiasAndersson I edited the answer, please try `driver.maximize_window()`

Comment: Yes driver.maximize_window() works but nothing happens with driver.execute_script('document.body.style.MozTransform = "scale(0.8)";')
driver.execute_script('document.body.style.MozTransformOrigin = "0 0";')

Comment: @TobiasAndersson I have updated the answer with a better solution. Please try `driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='80%'")`.

Comment: Zoom not working. `driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, executable_path=r"W:\geckodriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='80%'")`